# Вывод массива графически

Tags: .net, pascal, pascalabc.net

Программа Pascal abc net. модуль Grahp.

Здравствуйте!

Не получается вывести массив в столбец и строку. Получается в сплошную линию, когда использую textout. Скрин (1)

Когда использую write и writeln получается что массив выводится, но съезжает в область показано на скрине (2);

Вопрос: как сделать, чтоб вывод массива был под надписью или слева от неё?

```
  begin
     det:=(MAS1[1,1]*MAS1[2,2]*MAS1[3,3] //Вычисления опеределителя для проверки
        +MAS1[2,1]*MAS1[3,2]*MAS1[1,3]
        +MAS1[1,2]*MAS1[2,3]*MAS1[3,1])
        -(MAS1[3,1]*MAS1[2,2]*MAS1[1,3]
        +MAS1[3,2]*MAS1[2,3]*MAS1[1,1]
        +MAS1[2,1]*MAS1[1,2]*MAS1[3,3]);
     begin //Транспонирование матрицы
        for i1:=1 to m1 do
          begin
             for j1:=1 to n1 do MAS2[i1,j1]:=MAS1[j1,i1];
          end;
          // Итоговое нахождение обратной матрицы с решением             
        for i1:=1 to m1 do
           for j1:=1 to n1 do 
              MAS3[i1,j1]:=(1/det)*MAS2[i1,j1]; 
        SetFontColor(clNavy);
        SetFontSize(14);
        textout(10,30,' Обратная матрица: ');
        for i1:=1 to m1 do 
            begin // Готовая обратная матрица
               for j1:=1 to n1 do textout(200,30,MAS3[i1,j1]);
               writeln ();
            end;
     end;
  end;
```

http://itmages.ru/image/view/5247920/2555edb6 скрин 1

http://itmages.ru/image/view/5247921/f3924ca2 скрин 2

Answer (score 0):

```
program matrix;
uses GraphABC;
var
  MatrixOrigin: array[1..3, 1..3] of real;
  MatrixTransp: array[1..3, 1..3] of real;
  MatrixRevers: array[1..3, 1..3] of real;
  i, j: integer;
  det: real;
  s: string;
begin
  SetFontColor(clNavy);
  SetFontSize(14);
  TextOut(50, 20, 'Оригинальная матрица:');

  Randomize;
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    begin
      for j := 1 to 3 do
        begin
          MatrixOrigin[i, j] := Random(10);
          TextOut(100 + j * 50, 50 + i * 30, MatrixOrigin[i, j]);
        end;
    end;

  det := MatrixOrigin[1, 1] * MatrixOrigin[2, 2] * MatrixOrigin[3, 3]
       + MatrixOrigin[1, 2] * MatrixOrigin[2, 3] * MatrixOrigin[3, 1]
       + MatrixOrigin[1, 3] * MatrixOrigin[2, 1] * MatrixOrigin[3, 2]
       - MatrixOrigin[1, 3] * MatrixOrigin[2, 2] * MatrixOrigin[3, 1]
       - MatrixOrigin[1, 1] * MatrixOrigin[2, 3] * MatrixOrigin[3, 2]
       - MatrixOrigin[1, 2] * MatrixOrigin[2, 1] * MatrixOrigin[3, 3];

  TextOut(50, 190, 'Транспонированная матрица:');
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    begin
      for j := 1 to 3 do
        begin
          MatrixTransp[i, j] := MatrixOrigin[j, i];
          TextOut(100 + j * 50, 220 + i * 30, MatrixTransp[i, j]);
        end;
    end;

  TextOut(50, 360, 'Обратная матрица:');
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    begin
      for j := 1 to 3 do
        begin
          MatrixRevers[i, j] := (1 / det) * MatrixTransp[i, j];
          Str(MatrixRevers[i, j]:0:2, s);
          TextOut(100 + j * 50, 390 + i * 30, s);
        end;
    end;
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]